# String Index Out of Bounds with charAt

Tags: java, bluej

As a school project, I have been asked to make a program that displays Initials of the name you enter(*eg*.for Akshat Abhay Shetye it would display A. A. Shetye).

This works fine on my school PC which runs a old bluej and Java but throws an error(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range) when I run it.
This is my program:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class dispInitials{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your full name");
        String name = sc.next();
        //name = name.trim();
        String inName= name.charAt(0)+". ";
        int i = 1;
        for(i=1;i<(name.length()-1);i++){
            if(Character.isWhitespace(name.charAt(i)))
            break;
        }
        i++;
        inName=inName+name.charAt(i)+". ";
        for(i=i;i<name.length();i++){
            if(Character.isWhitespace(name.charAt(i)))
            break;
        }
        i++;
        System.out.println("The name is "+inName);
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain the error(at line 16)?

Comment: `i=i` must be a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your name input.

Replace your input line with this code:

```
String name = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: This seemed to fix the problem. But why does-String name = sc.next();-not work?

Comment: Because lets say 'Akshat Abhay Shetye' was your input.
sc.next() would get only 'Akshat' from your input and 'Abhay Shetye' would stay usless (untill sc.next() is called again).

I hope it clears your confusion?

Comment: Yep. But why does it work on the old BlueJ and Java?(my school PC)

Answer (score 4):

```
for(i=1;i<(name.length()-1);i++)
```

So, when the loop stops, `i`is equal to `name.length - 1`

Then, you're doing

```
i++;
inName = inName+name.charAt(i)+". ";
```

So you're trying to access the character at index `name.length`. But there is no such index. the last valid index is `name.length - 1`. Hence the exception.

You need to learn to use a debugger and step through the code line by line, inspecting the values of the variables along the way. Or at least to add `System.out.println()` instructions in the code to diagnose your problems. This is basically a developer's daily job.